# Optimum way to mask a two-dimension array using a condition on a one-dimension array

Tags: python, mask

I have an MxN numpy array of air quality data (M = latitude, N = longitude). I want to apply a mask to this data so that I mask out anything above the Equator (latitude > 0). However, my latitude data is unidimensional (M).

I can think of ways of masking these data, but they all seem too redundant and long. That is why I wanted to ask you what is, in your opinion, the best way of doing this.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.ma import masked_where

my_data = np.random.randn(10,5)
latitude = np.linspace(-5,4,10)
longitude = np.linspace(10,14,5)

# I would like something like this, if latitude had the same shape as my_data
masked_data = masked_where(latitude < 0, my_data)
```

So far I am using np.tile to expand latitude to the same shape as my_data. However, I wondered whether there is a smarter way of indexing or working around this. In conclusion: what is the best way to mask my_data, in your opinion?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just index `my_data` directly (`numpy` will automatically perform broadcasting of the mask):

```
my_data[latitude > 0]
```

Output:

```
(the last 4 rows of my_data)
```

Comment: That's great and simple. Thank you.

As an extra addition to the question. What if I wanted to include a condition on the second dimension (N)? For example: latitude > 0   AND   longitude < 13

Comment: `my_data[(latitude > 0) & (longitude < 13)]` will work! `numpy` indexing is actually pretty intuitive once you get used to it. [This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) link might help.